# Replacing thermostat receivers

Tags: thermostat

I am about to replace a BOSS RF receiver with a Hive one.

The BOSS receiver has LX (common), L, N, L1 (live feed to item to be controlled) and L2 (changeover contact).

The Hive one has N, L, common and then Heating off (NC) and Heating on (NO).

Is L1 the NC or NO equivalent? Consequently, L2 will be the other...

Comment: Your user name gave me a good laugh. Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing L1 = NO and L2 = NC. Wish me luck!

Comment: I would recommend holding off a bit. I'm not sure what impact miswiring would have on the HAVC and/or thermostat, but if you'll give it more than an hour, I'm sure someone will come along and give you some advice.

Comment: I was right ;-)

Comment: @LennyCrevice -- then post an answer describing how you hooked things up :)